# How to know height of react material textfield in other component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wrote code below to switch TextField and my custom component. But I can't set the height of the custom component with same height as TextField.
What can I do for this situation?

```js
<Grid item xs={12}>
<FormControlLabel 
    control={<Switch value={toggleView} onChange={e => setToggleView(e.target.checked)} />} 
    label="view" 
    style={{position: 'absolute', top: `-4%`, right:'0', zIndex: '9999'}}/>
{
    toggleView? <CustomComponent/> :
        <TextField 
        rows="10"
        multiline
        fullWidth={true}
        value={content}
        onChange={e => setContent(e.target.value)}
        label="content"
    />
}
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change textFiled height and other properties in various ways like:

1. the sx prop:

```
     <TextField
          sx={{ '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': { height: '50px' } }} // change height form here
          variant="outlined"
        />
```

2. Mui styled component way(using emotion)

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'

export const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)(() => ({
  '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
    height: 50
  }
}))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can I set my custom component's height to TextField? I want my custom component to be set to rows=10